# Euler 43 - is there a monad to help write this list comprehension?

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension, monads

Here is a way to solve Euler problem 43 (please let me know if this doesn't give the correct answer). Is there a monad or some other syntatic sugar which could assist with keeping track of the `notElem` conditions?

```
toNum xs = foldl (\s d -> s*10+d) 0 xs

numTest xs m = (toNum xs) `mod` m == 0

pandigitals = [ [d0,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7,d8,d9] |
                d7 <- [0..9],
                d8 <- [0..9], d8 `notElem` [d7],
                d9 <- [0..9], d9 `notElem` [d8,d7],
                numTest [d7,d8,d9] 17,
                d5 <- [0,5],  d5 `notElem` [d9,d8,d7],
                d3 <- [0,2,4,6,8], d3 `notElem` [d5,d9,d8,d7],
                d6 <- [0..9], d6 `notElem` [d3,d5,d9,d8,d7],
                numTest [d6,d7,d8] 13,
                numTest [d5,d6,d7] 11,
                d4 <- [0..9], d4 `notElem` [d6,d3,d5,d9,d8,d7],
                numTest [d4,d5,d6] 7,
                d2 <- [0..9], d2 `notElem` [d4,d6,d3,d5,d9,d8,d7],
                numTest [d2,d3,d4] 3,
                d1 <- [0..9], d1 `notElem` [d2,d4,d6,d3,d5,d9,d8,d7],
                d0 <- [1..9], d0 `notElem` [d1,d2,d4,d6,d3,d5,d9,d8,d7]
              ]

main = do
         let nums = map toNum pandigitals
         print $ nums
         putStrLn ""
         print $ sum nums
```

For instance, in this case the assignment to `d3` is not optimal - it really should be moved to just before the `numTest [d2,d3,d4] 3` test. Doing that, however, would mean changing some of the `notElem` tests to remove `d3` from the list being checked. Since the successive `notElem` lists are obtained by just consing the last chosen value to the previous list, it seems like this should be doable - somehow.

UPDATE: Here is the above program re-written with Louis' `UniqueSel` monad below:

```
toNum xs = foldl (\s d -> s*10+d) 0 xs
numTest xs m = (toNum xs) `mod` m == 0

pandigitalUS =
  do d7 <- choose
     d8 <- choose
     d9 <- choose
     guard $ numTest [d7,d8,d9] 17
     d6 <- choose
     guard $ numTest [d6,d7,d8] 13
     d5 <- choose
     guard $ d5 == 0 || d5 == 5
     guard $ numTest [d5,d6,d7] 11
     d4 <- choose
     guard $ numTest [d4,d5,d6] 7
     d3 <- choose
     d2 <- choose
     guard $ numTest [d2,d3,d4] 3
     d1 <- choose
     guard $ numTest [d1,d2,d3] 2
     d0 <- choose
     guard $ d0 /= 0
     return [d0,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7,d8,d9]

pandigitals = map snd $ runUS pandigitalUS [0..9]

main = do print $ pandigitals
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure.

```
newtype UniqueSel a = UniqueSel {runUS :: [Int] -> [([Int], a)]}
instance Monad UniqueSel where
  return a = UniqueSel (\ choices -> [(choices, a)])
  m >>= k = UniqueSel (\ choices -> 
    concatMap (\ (choices', a) -> runUS (k a) choices')
      (runUS m choices))

instance MonadPlus UniqueSel where
  mzero = UniqueSel $ \ _ -> []
  UniqueSel m `mplus` UniqueSel k = UniqueSel $ \ choices ->
    m choices ++ k choices

-- choose something that hasn't been chosen before
choose :: UniqueSel Int
choose = UniqueSel $ \ choices ->
  [(pre ++ suc, x) | (pre, x:suc) <- zip (inits choices) (tails choices)]
```

and then you treat it like the List monad, with `guard` to enforce choices, except that it won't choose an item more than once.  Once you have a `UniqueSel [Int]` computation, just do `map snd (runUS computation [0..9])` to give it `[0..9]` as the choices to select from.

Comment: I'm getting a type error: `runUS choices` is a function `[Int] -> [([Int], a0)]`, but the compiler is expecting just `[([Int], a)]`

Comment: The `(runUS choices)` should have been `(runUS m choices)`

Comment: Also, is `guard` from `Control.Monad`? If so, what would `mzero` be for `UniqueSel`?

Comment: Looks like `StateT [Int] []`.

Comment: @luqui, I'm not 100% sure it's the same -- I'm not 100% sure which is `StateT [Int] []` and which is `ListT (State [Int])`.

Comment: `ListT (State [Int])` is `s -> ([a], s)` (broken).  The correct ListT can't be built out of primitive types without `Mu`. But think intuitively: it's a nondeterministic computation with a state running through it (the state is "on top" of the nondeterminism).

Comment: Fair enough, but IMO, more obvious to understand when it's described specifically as a "unique choice monad."  Meh.

Answer (score 4):

Before jumping to monads, let's consider ***guided unique selection* from finite domains** first:

```hs
-- all possibilities:
pick_any []     = []       
pick_any (x:xs) = (xs,x) : [ (x:dom,y) | (dom,y) <- pick_any xs ]

-- guided selection (assume there's no repetitions in the domain):
one_of ns xs = [ (dom,y) | let choices = pick_any xs, n <- ns,
                           (dom,y) <- take 1 $ filter ((==n).snd) choices ]
```

With this a list comprehension can be written without the use of `elem` calls:

```
p43 = sum [ fromDigits [d0,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7,d8,d9]
            | (dom5,d5) <- one_of [0,5] [0..9]
            , (dom6,d6) <- pick_any dom5          
            , (dom7,d7) <- pick_any dom6          
            , rem (100*d5+10*d6+d7) 11 == 0 
            ....

fromDigits    :: (Integral a) => [a] -> Integer
fromDigits ds = foldl' (\s d-> s*10 + fromIntegral d) 0 ds
```

The monad from [Louis Wasserman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831374/euler-43-is-there-a-monad-to-help-write-this-list-comprehension/9831493#9831493) can be further augmented with additional operations based on the functions above:

```
import Control.Monad 

newtype UniqueSel a = UniqueSel { runUS :: [Int] -> [([Int], a)] }
instance Monad UniqueSel where
  -- as in Louis's answer

instance MonadPlus UniqueSel where
  -- as in Louis's answer

choose             = UniqueSel pick_any   
choose_one_of xs   = UniqueSel $ one_of xs
choose_n n         = replicateM n choose
set_choices cs     = UniqueSel (\ _ -> [(cs, ())])
get_choices        = UniqueSel (\cs -> [(cs, cs)])
```

So that we can write

```
numTest xs m = fromDigits xs `rem` m == 0

pandigitalUS :: UniqueSel [Int]
pandigitalUS = do
     set_choices [0..9]
     [d7,d8,d9] <- choose_n 3
     guard $ numTest [d7,d8,d9] 17
     d6 <- choose
     guard $ numTest [d6,d7,d8] 13
     d5 <- choose_one_of [0,5]
     guard $ numTest [d5,d6,d7] 11
     d4 <- choose
     guard $ numTest [d4,d5,d6] 7
     d3 <- choose_one_of [0,2..8]
     d2 <- choose
     guard $ rem (d2+d3+d4) 3 == 0 
     [d1,d0] <- choose_n 2
     guard $ d0 /= 0
     return [d0,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7,d8,d9]

pandigitals = map (fromDigits.snd) $ runUS pandigitalUS []

main = do print $ sum pandigitals
```

Comment: if you write `fromDigits` to have type `Num a => [a] -> Integer`, you can keep `d0`, ... `d9` as Ints since no overflow will occur in the `rem` calls.

Comment: thanks for showing the `set_choices`, `choose_one`, `choose_n` and `select` functions

Comment: @user5402 thanks for the suggestion. :) It worked, with `Integral` context though. Will edit.

Answer (score 3):

The `UniqueSel` monad suggested by Louis Wasserman is exactly `StateT [Integer] []` (I'm using `Integer` everywhere for simplicity).

The state keeps the available digits and every computation is nondeterministic - from a given state we can select different digits to continue with. Now the `choose` function can be implemented as

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Data.List

choose :: PanM Integer
choose = do
    xs <- get
    x <- lift xs -- pick one of `xs`
    let xs' = x `delete` xs
    put xs'
    return x
```

And then the monad is run by `evalStateT` as

```
main = do
         let nums = evalStateT pandigitals [0..9]
         -- ...
```