# List all possible 4 chooses from 9 in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm not able to find an effective way to pick out all permutations of 4 elements from a list of 9 elements in Haskell.
The python-way to do the same thing:

```
itertools.permutations(range(9+1),4)
```

An not so effective way to do it in Haskell:

```
nub . (map (take 4)) . permutations $ [1..9]
```

I would like to find something like:

```
permutations 4 [1..9]
```

Comment: here is a similar SO question which can address this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831374/euler-43-is-there-a-monad-to-help-write-this-list-comprehension

Comment: @user5402 sorry I'm not that hax at Haskell (yet), I can't really see the resemblance.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my solution:

```
import Control.Arrow

select :: [a] -> [(a, [a])]
select [] = []
select (x:xs) = (x, xs) : map (second (x:)) (select xs)

perms :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
perms 0 _  = [[]]
perms n xs = do
    (y, ys) <- select xs
    fmap (y:) (perms (n - 1) ys)
```

It's very lazy and even works for infinite lists, although the output there is not very useful.  I didn't bother implementing diagonalization or something like that.  For finite lists it's fine.

Comment: Without using `Control.Arrow`, `select` can be written as: `select (x:xs) = (x,xs) : [ (y,x:ys) | (y,ys) <- select xs ]`, with the additional base case: `select [x] = [(x,[])]`.

Comment: @Ibolla: your "additional base case" is already covered by `select [] = []`

Comment: @newacct: no, my additional base case is `select [x]`, not `select []`.

Comment: @Ibolla: but `select [x]` is `select (x:[])`, which by your recursive case becomes `select (x:[]) = (x,[]) : [(y,x:ys) | (y,ys) <- select []]`. Since we already have `select [] = []`, that list comprehension becomes `[]`, so we get `(x,[]) : []`, which is the same as `[(x,[])]`

Answer (score 2):

```
pick :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
pick 0 _ = [[]]
pick _ [] = []
pick n (x : xs) = map (x :) (pick (n - 1) xs) ++ pick n xs

perms :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
perms n l = pick n l >>= permutations
```

Answer (score 1):

```
replicateM 4 [1..9]
```

Will do this for you, I believe. It's in `Control.Monad`.

Comment: `replicateM` doesn't produce lists of distinct elements, though

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
import Data.List (delete)

perms :: (Eq a) => Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
perms 0 _  = [[]]
perms _ [] = [[]]
perms n xs = [ (x:ys) | x <- xs, ys <- perms (n-1) (delete x xs) ]
```

Basically, it says, a permutation of n elements from a set is, pick any element as the first element of the result, then the rest is a permutation of n-1 elements from the rest of the set. Plus some base cases. Assumes that elements in the list are unique.

Comment: But that's slower than ertes' solution, and the `Eq` constraint isn't really nice.