# how to assign values to a list in haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a data type:

```
data Numbers = Numbers {a::Int, b::Int}
```

How can I construct `[Numbers]` in order to get the same effect as

```
[[a,b] | a <- [1,2], b <- (filter (/=a) [1,2])]
```

so the result will be similar to `[[1,2],[2,1]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `Numbers` as the constructor (note: `[]` is also a constructor, only with a specific syntax sugar, so there is no fundamental difference).

```
data Numbers = Numbers {a::Int, b::Int}
               deriving Show

main = print [ Numbers a b | a <- [1, 2], b <- filter (/=a) [1, 2] ]

> main
[Numbers {a = 1, b = 2},Numbers {a = 2, b = 1}]
```

Comment: if it is a really big list, like a<-[1..100] b<-[1..100], how can i implement it in a hs file ? can i do sth like [Numbers] = [Numbers a b | a<-[1..100], b<- filter (/=a) [1..100]]

Comment: @Z.pyyyy, yes, sort of, `x = [Numbers a b | a <- [1..100], b <- filter (/= a) [1..100]]`.

Comment: @Z.pyyyy Read some haskell turorial like YAHT or real world haskell.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be nothing but a selection with removal.  You can find efficient code to do that in an [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766449/list-all-possible-4-chooses-from-9-in-haskell).

If it's certainly about exactly two elements, then this implementation will be efficient:

```
do x:ys <- tails [1..3]
   y <- ys
   [(x, y), (y, x)]
```

Comment: I think the question's quite clear that it's about more than two elements, but yes, that works in this case.