# Does <- implicitly coerce types in a Haskell do block?

Tags: haskell, types, monads

My question relates to the answer to another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11766789/3212958

In his answer, ertes writes the following type signature

```
select :: [a] -> [(a, [a])]
```

However, when `select` is actually used, ertes writes the following inside of a `do` block

```
(y, ys) <- select xs
```

Please help me shed some light on how the tuple `(y, ys)` matches the return type of select, namely `[(a, [a])]`. Is Haskell coercing the types at some point? (Does Haskell ever coerce types?) Is `<-` extracting a tuple of type `(a, [a])` from the list monad that `select` returns?

Thanks,
Max

**--- EDIT: ---**

@Lee reminds newbs to desugar before trying to reason about types. After making `>>=` explicit, it's more clear what's going on. After desugaring, the function in question looks like:

```
select xs >>= \(y, ys) -> fmap (y:) (perms (n - 1) ys)
```

And for lists, `xs >>= f = concat (map f xs)`. So a better reading of `(y, ys)` in this context is as the signature of the function to map over the list.

Comment: `select` returns a list. If you write `a <- select xs` then `a` is every element of `select xs`. If you later write `func a`, the result of that is the result of applying `func` to every element of `select xs`. This is just how the list monad is defined. `a <- select xs; func a` is the same as `select xs >>= func`. Bind for lists is defined as : `m >>= f = concat (map f m)`, so you are writing `map func (select xs)`. There is no type coercion in haskell.

Comment: @user2407038 some slight technicality here; `a` is not 'every element', `a` represents *one* (arbitrary but specific) element of the list.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In `do` notation,

```
do x1 <- action1
   action2
```

is translated into `action1 >>= \x1 -> action2`

This means that if `action1` has type `m a` for some monad `m`, then `x1` has type `a`. It's not really coercing types, but rather 'unpacking' the value from the monadic action `action1` and binding it to `x1`.

Answer (score 4):

`(y, ys)` is of type `(b, c)`

The return type of `select` is of type `[(a, [a])]`

In `<-` the types are actually `d` and `Monad m => m d`. So we can write the following type equalities:

```
(b, c) ~ d
[(a, [a])] ~ Monad m => m d
```

Solving is easy. First substitute `d` from first equation into second equation:

```
[(a, [a])] ~ Monad m => m (b, c)
```

Now to see what's going on I will use a prefix form of [] type constructor (it's not valid haskell but you should get the idea):

```
[] (a, [a]) ~ Monad m => m ( b, c)
```

So

```
m ~ []
(a, [a]) ~ (b, c)
```

At this point the compiler checks that `instance Monad [a]` exists. The rest is easy:

```
a ~ b
[a] ~ c
```

Comment: `[] (a, [] a)` is valid Haskell actually, or even `[] ((,) a ([] a))` if you like.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that the type constructor for `[]` can be used this way, just like the value constructor.

Comment: Yeah, I was pleasantly surprised to learn it too. Certainly makes it easier to explain the list monad.