# Haskell filter string with only the first occuring Char

Tags: haskell

I want to filter a string with a string.
What I want is to use delete every first occurring char.

```
myFunc :: String -> String -> String
```

Like:

```
myFunc "dddog" "bigdddddog" = "biddg"
```

In `"dddog"`: 3x d, 1x o, 1x g

In the second string it removed 3x d, 1x o and 1x g
So the output: `biddg`

I can't use filter for it, because it will delete all occurring chars.
And I struggled a long time with it.

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Not entirely sure what you want do do. Another example?

Comment: Shouldn't the output be "biddg"? Or am I misunderstanding? With your output it looks like you deleted the first 4 ds, the first o, and the second g.

Comment: yeah you are right;) srry for the misunderstanding

Comment: If you have `myFunc :: String -> String -> String`, what is the result of `myFunc s1 s2` for any two Strings? Are you simply removing all of `s1` from the end of `s2`?

Comment: Note that I have given the function a name. I suggest that you edit your question similarly since it will help clarify what you are asking.

Comment: yeah what i want is to use the chars from s1 to remove the chars from s2.

Comment: In your question, you give two different outputs for `myFunc "dddog" "bigdddddog"`, `"biddg"` and `"bigd"` - which I suppose is meant to be `"bigdd"`. Which one do you mean?

Comment: what should be the result of `myFunc "dddog" "bdigdogd"`?

Comment: @Clare93 you're supposed to accept one of the answers, one that was the most helpful for you.

Answer (score 11):

How about

```
Prelude> :m +Data.List
Prelude Data.List> "bigdddddog" \\ "dddog"
"biddg"
```

Comment: Nice many thanks to you and other people who tried to help me:)
i didn't think it would be so simple.

Answer (score 4):

Not the nicest solution, but you can understand easier what's going on:

```
myfunc :: String -> String -> String    
myfunc [] xs = xs
myfunc (x:xs) ys = myfunc xs $ remove x ys 
    where 
        remove _ [] = []
        remove x (y:ys) = if x == y then ys else y : remove x ys
```

As you commented, you want to use guards. Do you mean this?

```
myfunc :: String -> String -> String    
myfunc [] xs = xs
myfunc (x:xs) ys = myfunc xs $ remove x ys 

remove :: Char -> String -> String       
remove _ [] = []
remove x (y:ys) 
    | x == y    = ys
    | otherwise = y : remove x ys
```

Comment: uh? where did your comment go? strange

Comment: your `remove` is actually equivalent to `Data.List.delete`, and the recursion pattern of `myfunc` amounts to `myfunc = flip (foldl (flip remove))` which is how `Data.List.(\\)` is defined, [apparently](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/Data-List.html#%5C%5C). :) IOW, `myfunc == flip Data.List.(\\)`.

Comment: Yeah it wasn't necessary anymore because i made a working function with guards later on so i deleted my comment. But thnx anyway for your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

some of the other solutions don't seem to produce the same result you posted. I think I have a simple solution that does what you asked for but I may be misunderstanding what you want. All I do in the following code is go though the list and apply 'delete' to every element in the list. It's not exactly efficient but it gets the job done.

```
import Data.List

myFunc (x:xs) ys = myFunc xs (delete x ys)
myFunc []     ys = ys
```

There are perhaps more efficient solutions like storing the "to remove" list in a tree with the number of occurences stored as the value then traversing the main list testing to see if the count at that key was still greater than zero. I think that would give you O(n*lg(m)) (where n is the size of the list to be removed from and m is the size of the "to remove" list) rather than O(n*m) as is the case above. This version could also be maid to be lazy I think.

edit:

Here is the tree version I was talking abut using Data.Map. It's a bit complex but should be more efficient for large lists and it is somewhat lazy

```
myFunc l ys = myFunc' (makeCount l) ys
    where makeCount xs = foldr increment (Map.fromList []) xs
          increment x a = Map.insertWith (+) x 1 a
          decrement x a = Map.insertWith (flip (-)) x 1 a
          getCount x a = case Map.lookup x a of
              Just c  -> c
              Nothing -> 0
          myFunc' counts (x:xs) = if (getCount x counts) > 0
                                  then myFunc' (decrement x counts) xs
                                  else x : myFunc' counts xs
          myFunc' _ []          = []
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure about how you want your function to behave, how about this?

```
import Data.List (isPrefixOf)

myFunc :: String -> String -> String
myFunc _ [] = []
myFunc y x'@(x:xs) | y `isPrefixOf` x' = drop (length y) x'
                   | otherwise         = x : myFilter xs y
```

This gives the following output in GHCi:

```
> myFunc "dddog" "bigdddddog" 
> "bigdd"
```

If this is not what you had in mind, please give another input/output example.

Answer (score 1):

I like kaan's elegant solution. In case you meant this...here's one where the "ddd" would only be removed if matched as a whole:

```
import Data.List (group,isPrefixOf,delete)

f needles str = g (group needles) str where
  g needles []         = []
  g needles xxs@(x:xs)
    | null needle' = [x] ++ g needles xs
    | otherwise    = let needle = head needle'
                     in g (delete needle needles) (drop (length needle) xxs)
   where needle' = dropWhile (not . flip isPrefixOf xxs) needles
```

Output:

```
*Main> f "dddog" "bigdddddog"
"biddg"

*Main> f "dddog" "bdigdogd"
"bdidgd"
```

Answer (score 1):

No monadic solution yet, there you go:

```
import Control.Monad.State

myFunc :: String -> State String String
myFunc [] = return ""
myFunc (x:xs) = get >>= f where
  f [] = return (x:xs)
  f (y:ys) = if y == x then put ys >> myFunc xs
             else myFunc xs >>= return . (x:)

main = do
      let (a,b) = runState (myFunc "bigdddddog") "dddog" in
        putStr a
```

Answer (score 0):

Using predefined functions from Data.List,

```
-- mapAccumL :: (acc -> x -> (acc, y)) -> acc -> [x] -> (acc, [y])
-- lookup :: (Eq a) => a -> [(a, b)] -> Maybe b

{-# LANGUAGE PatternGuards #-}
import Data.List

picks []     = []       -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/9889702/849891
picks (x:xs) = (x,xs) : [ (y,x:ys) | (y,ys) <- picks xs]

myFunc a b = concat . snd $ mapAccumL f (picks a) b
  where
    f acc x | Just r <- lookup x acc = (picks r,[])
    f acc x = (acc,[x])
```

Testing:

```
Prelude Data.List> myFunc "dddog" "bigdddddog"
"biddg"
```

*edit*: this is of course a bit more complex than `(\\)`. I'll let it stand as an illustration. There could be some merit to it still, as it doesn't copy the 2nd (longer?) string over and over, for each non-matching character from the 1st (shorter) string, as `delete` apparently does, used in [`(\\) = foldl (flip delete)`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/Data-List.html#%5C%5C).